# Use is_bitstring or is_binary in Elixir Guard for String?

Tags: elixir

Let's take this simple function:

```
  @spec laBionda(String.t()) :: String.t()
  def laBionda(name \\ "you") when is_bitstring(name) do
    "One for #{name}, one for me"
  end
```

I only want to define the function for String inputs.

Should I use `is_bitstring` or `is_binary` on the Guard? Are there any differences? Both seem to be fine in that case.

Comment: A bitstring is a type that stores arbitrary number of bits, you can have a 3bit bitstring whereas binary stores arbitrary number of bytes. A binary is just a collection of bytes, so it has to have a number of bits that is divisible by 8. So to avoid confusion best to use `is_binary` for your ascii strings. See also here https://elixirforum.com/t/bitstring-and-binary/2351#post_2

Comment: There is a great talk about strings that explains the differences: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZxBL-lV9uA

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use `is_binary/1`.

Strings in Elixir are represented as binaries. Elixir binaries are sequences of bytes, whereas bitstrings are sequences of bits. While all binaries are bitstrings, not all bitstrings are binaries.

`is_bitstring/1` can return `true` for some bitstrings that cannot be represented as a binary, for example, the single bit:

```elixir
iex(1)> is_binary(<<1::1>>)
false
iex(2)> is_bitstring(<<1::1>>)
true
```

You expect strings only. Bitstrings that are not binaries are never desired, so the more specific `is_binary/1` is the better choice.

Answer (score 7):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10821192/10895259

The difference between in a binary and a bitstring is that the length of a binary is evenly divisible by 8, i.e. it contains no 'partial' bytes; a bitstring has no such restriction.

The example from [guides](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#binaries-and-bitstrings) demonstrates this difference.

```
iex> is_binary(<<100 :: size(9)>>)
false
iex> is_binary(<<100 :: size(8)>>)
true
iex> is_binary(<<100 :: size(7)>>)
false
```

In your function, it does not matter what guard to use.
But `is_binary/1` is a convention, as the strings are stored in bytes.

Comment: It does matter which will be used there, as `is_bitstring/1` will pass invalid "Elixir strings", for example `"foo #{<<100 :: size(7)>>} bar"` will fail as `String.Chars` is not implemented for bit strings.